# Stop jQuery anitmation with media query

Tags: jquery, media-queries

Hello guys I have this simple jquery animation

```
    $(window).load(function() {

        //Top Header Logo Expand
$("#logo-expand").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "170px"
    }, 300 );
});

$("#logo-expand").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "56px"
    }, 300 );
});

    });
```

Now I want to disable the animation when I am in a phone resolution, how can i do that with jquery media queries, any idea?

Here's my http://jsfiddle.net/MyKnB/5/

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `window.innerWidth` to determine the width of the screen and perform animation only if it is greater than certain width

```
$(window).load(function() {
if (window.innerWidth > 700){
    //Top Header Logo Expand
$("#logo-expand").mouseenter(function() {
$(this).animate({
    width: "170px"
}, 300 );
});

$("#logo-expand").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).animate({
    width: "56px"
}, 300 );
}
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
if($(window).width() > 320) {
    $("#logo-expand").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "170px"
        }, 300 );
    });

    $("#logo-expand").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "56px"
        }, 300 );
    });
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyKnB/7/

For best results, you'd probably want to throw that into a function and call it on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

not using media queries as im not sure its possible but I hope this helps
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRLqz/)

effectivly it checks the window size and then runs the animations or not

```
$("#logo-expand").mouseenter(function() {
  if($(window).width() > 100){  
    $(this).animate({
        width: "170px"
    }, 300 );
  } else {
    $(this).css({'width':"170px"});                               
  }
});

$("#logo-expand").mouseleave(function() {
if($(window).width() > 100){ 
    $(this).animate({
              width: "56px"
        }, 300 );
    } else {
       $(this).css({'width':"56px"});                               
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I miss understood whether you still wanted the CSS style to be applied